# Hi! I'm trying to implement the same functionality duolingo in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to implement the same functionality, where word choices are offered as separate buttons and by clicking on them they are moved to the line, creating a sentence. Just like duolingo.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/St5vN.jpg)

I started doing it through TextFiled and text, but something tells me that's not a good solution.

How would you implement something like this?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Screen6_1_3 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Screen6_1_3({super.key});

  @override
  State<Screen6_1_3> createState() => _Screen6_1_3State();
}

class _Screen6_1_3State extends State<Screen6_1_3> {
  String textOne = "Bread";


  var colorite = Colors.white;

  TextEditingController textarea = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        leading: GestureDetector(
          child: Icon(
            Icons.close,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                context, "home", (route) => false);
          },
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Container(
                width: 70,
                height: 50,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 226, 226, 226),
                  border: Border.all(
                    color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 123, 123, 123),
                    width: 2,
                  ),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                ),
                child: TextField(
                  enableSuggestions: false,
                  autocorrect: false,
                  controller: textarea,
                  maxLines: 1,
                  readOnly: false,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 123, 123, 123))),
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      textarea.clear();
                      textOne = 'Bread';
                      colorite = Colors.white;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    if (textarea.text.isEmpty) {
                      insert('Bread');
                      textOne = 'Bread';
                      colorite = Colors.transparent;
                    }
                  });
                },
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(13.0),
                  child: Container(
                    decoration:
                        BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.white)),
                    child: Text(
                      textOne,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: colorite,
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void insert(String content) {
    var text = textarea.text;
    var pos = textarea.selection.start;
    textarea.value = TextEditingValue(
      text: text.substring(0, pos) + content + text.substring(pos),
      selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: pos + content.length),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be pretty easy to implement if you use `Draggable` widgets for the words and `DragTarget` for the textfields.

> Youtube Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QzA4c4QHZCY
>
> And a great example you might relate to :
> https://mobikul.com/draggable-widget-in-flutter/

I'd recommend trying to watch the video first to get an idea about how `Draggable` widget works and then trying to implement it in your project by taking inspiration from the article that I've provided.

Comment: Thank you! 
Yes, but I can not understand how to implement not drag and drop objects, and when you click on an object, it automatically went there?
Tried to wrap it in GestureDetector - onTap, no further action.

Comment: You need to drag the object and yes you can also implement click to snap it to the `DragTarget` as well.

Comment: could you give me an example of how you can implement a dragclick transfer in dragtarget? I would be very grateful to you.

Comment: yeah sure here is the link for an example https://medium.flutterdevs.com/draggable-and-drag-target-in-flutter-2513ea7c09f2#:~:text=accepted%20by%20DragTarget.-,DragTarget,-As%20the%20name

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to clarify onTap.